# How can I monitor disk io?

Tags: linux, disk

I'd like to do some general disk io monitoring on a debian linux server. What are the tools I should know about that monitor disk io so I can see if a disk's performance is maxed out or spikes at certain time throughout the day?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/9428/how-can-i-monitor-hard-disk-load-on-linux || http://superuser.com/questions/115358/linux-is-there-something-similar-to-top-for-i-o

Answer (score 307, accepted):

For disk I/O trending there are a few options. My personal favorite is the `sar` command from `sysstat`. By default, it gives output like this:

```
09:25:01 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
09:35:01 AM     all      0.11      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00     99.88
09:45:01 AM     all      0.12      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00     99.86
09:55:01 AM     all      0.09      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00     99.90
10:05:01 AM     all      0.10      0.00      0.01      0.02      0.01     99.86
Average:        all      0.19      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.01     99.78
```

The `%iowait` is the time spent waiting on I/O. Using the Debian package, you must enable the stat collector via the `/etc/default/sysstat` config file after package installation.

To see current utilization broken out by device, you can use the `iostat` command, also from the sysstat package:

```
$ iostat -x 1
Linux 3.5.2-x86_64-linode26 (linode)    11/08/2012      _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.84    0.00    0.08    1.22    0.07   97.80

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.09     1.02    2.58    0.49   112.79    12.11    40.74     0.15   48.56   3.88   1.19
xvdb              1.39     0.43    4.03    1.82    43.33    18.43    10.56     0.66  112.73   1.93   1.13
```

Some other options that can show disk usage in trending graphs is [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) and [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/).

Comment: Munin or Cacti are more what I'm looking for. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Note that %iowait only shows time when the kernel had nothing else to do but wait for IO. On a 100% CPU bound server this will be zero regardless how much IO it is doing.

Comment: iostat -x dm-0 | grep Device; iostat -xd 2 -y dm-0 | grep dm-0

Comment: to enable ```sar```, one can simply do ```vim /etc/default/sysstat``` set ```"false"``` to ```"true"``` save the file and then do a ```sudo service sysstat restart```

Comment: This yields `sar: command not found`

Comment: @user7860670 `sar` is part of the sysstat package. You must install `sysstat` to use.

Comment: Alright, i've installed sysstat package for ubuntu 18.04, modified `/etc/default/sysstat` line `ENABLED="true"`, however `sar` command now outputs `Cannot open /var/log/sysstat/sa01: No such file or directory
Please check if data collecting is enabled`, i guess it requires service support? Is it possible to run service process manually?

Answer (score 153):

Have a look at `iotop`:

```bsh
Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :       0.00 B/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND                                                                                                             
    1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init splash
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    4 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/0:0H]
    6 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [mm_percpu_wq]
    7 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
    8 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_sched]
```

Or `iodump`, if that's more down your way of thinking.

Note: This requires at least [kernel 2.6.20](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) to work.

Comment: This is not just Linux only, but also requires a newer (or patched) kernel.

Comment: These look good for finding out what's going on right now, but I'm looking for bigger picture monitoring.

Comment: @camomileCase - you didn't specify that in your question ...

Comment: on ubuntu 18.04 iotop crashes with messages `OSError: Netlink error: No such file or directory (2)`

Comment: @user7860670 - I can't confirm this; a cursory search suggests that there's a problem with iotop in containers - are you running docker or something?

Comment: Yes, i'm using docker.

Answer (score 123):

I like `dstat`. It can show totals and statistics per disk and even md-devices (RAID), also can use colors for better overview:

```
$ dstat -tdD total,sda,sdb,sdc,md1 60 
----system---- -dsk/total----dsk/sda-----dsk/sdb-----dsk/sdc-----dsk/md1--
     time     | read  writ: read  writ: read  writ: read  writ: read  writ
08-11 22:08:17|3549k  277k: 144k   28k: 851k   62k: 852k   60k:  25k   82k
08-11 22:09:17|  60k  258k:1775B   15k:  13k   63k:  15k   60k:  68B   74k
08-11 22:10:17| 176k  499k:   0    14k:  41k  122k:  41k  125k: 273B  157k
08-11 22:11:17|  42k  230k:   0    14k:9830B   54k:  14k   51k:   0    70k
08-11 22:11:52|  28k  132k:   0  5032B:5266B   33k:9479B   28k:   0    37k
```

- `-t` for timestamps
- `-d` for disk statistics
- `-D` to specify the exact devices to report
- `60` to average over 60 seconds. The display is updated every second, but only once per 60 seconds a new line will be started.
- not used in this example, but `-c` can report wait IO percentage, which in most cases is related to the CPU waiting for data from the disks.

It is available for most Linux distributions, but sometimes needs to be installed from repositories.

Comment: I used this, and don't get the 'k' suffix, just numbers like 135 read 157 writ. What are the units here? Megabytes?

Comment: This yields `dstat: command not found`

Comment: @user7860670 that means it's not installed... Run `<apt/yum/dnf> search dstat` to find the package name and install it first.

Answer (score 70):

Just from [files on your computer](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/iostats.txt) (assuming a recent kernel) you can ask `/sys/block/sda/stat` (documented at [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/stat.txt)) or `/proc/diskstats`.  It will need some translating, however.  But it's nice for a quick and dirty check.

Comment: Big advantage for this answer is that no tools need to be installed. It's just there. (Potentially :-)

Comment: e.g. echo "read io      merge  sectors   ticks  write io merges  sectors   ticks     inflight ioticks  timeinqueu";cat /sys/block/vda/vda1/stat ;sleep 10; cat /sys/block/vda/vda1/stat

Answer (score 60):

Another option is to use: `sudo iotop -aoP`

```
-a    Will show accumulated output
-o    Will only output 
-P    Will only show processes instead of threads
```

This program will tell you how much a process has written to disk and read from disk since iotop was started.

Comment: I hear something accessing the disk, but accumulated output is increasing very slowly, sometimes not at all in a second... ???

Comment: If you hear the disk, it's probably old and/or slow. Modern HDDs tend to be very quiet. What kind of sounds is it making? Use `smartctl` to see whether the disk is healthy.

Answer (score 11):

Monitoring Disk Io can be done by multiple tools like the following.

1. Iostat
2. Iozone
3. SAR
4. vmstat

Also some important operating system concepts are very much necessary to comprehend them..read the [Linux IO complete tutorial](http://www.slashroot.in/linux-system-io-monitoring)

Comment: iozone is for testing, not monitoring: "Iozone is a filesystem benchmark tool. The benchmark generates and measures a variety of file operations."

Answer (score 10):

Why not try [nmon](http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php). It does disks and network with processes. Originally for AIX but it has been ported to Linux for some years now.

Answer (score 10):

I am the author of [`diskgraph`](https://github.com/stolk/diskgraph) which is a command line tool that plots the disk IO in a terminal. You select which disk, as an argument on the command-line, like `sda` or `nvme0n1`.

```
$ ./diskgraph nvme0n1
```

[image: diskgraph screenshot]

In red: the write bandwidth

In green: the read bandwidth

In orange: the number of IO operations that are in-flight.

---

Please note that this utility depends on features introduced in Linux 5. In other words, it will not work with Linux 4 or earlier.

Answer (score 9):

Another great tool for a quick overview where the load comes from is [`atop`](http://www.atoptool.nl/)

It can show you an overview over all resources (CPU, memory/swap, network and disk I/O) or you can drill down to a single resource and sort processes by how much they consume.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `zfs`, then there is a built in tool for this:

```
% zpool iostat -T d -n -H -v 1 | head -5
Sat Dec 24 23:09:49 2022
datatank    24.8T   31.6T   39  70  5.76M   4.55M
mirror-0    4.29T   4.80T   3   9   802K    765K
gpt/slot_A1 -   -   2   4   511K    403K
gpt/slot_B7 -   -   1   4   335K    405K
```

- The `-T d` option puts the date lines (e.g Dec 24).
- The `-H` enables scripted mode by omitting headers and making the data well formed.
- The `-v` enables statistics for each individual vdev in the pool.
- Finally the 1 is how many seconds to wait for the next update.
- The `head -5` is just to demonstrate you can pipe the output.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do if you want to see performance on a long period is to use [Centreon](http://www.centreon.com/)
which is a powerful tools build on [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org). Centreon make you able to monitor by drawing graphs of resource's performances and lot of other things.

Comment: What other things? Any screenshots? Please expand your answer.