# "Task manager" for killing hard-disk intensive processes?

Tags: debian, process, hard-disk, kill

Sometimes I want to be able to quickly kill the process that has the most intensive hard disk usage. How do I do it?

With the solutions described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55212/how-can-i-monitor-disk-io) I would have to open another terminal to invoke a kill. Is there a way to monitor and potentially kill with the same app?

Comment: What flavor of unix?

Comment: @thrig I'm using Debian

Comment: @StephenC it doesn't say there how I kill it. With the solutions there I would have to open another terminal to invoke a kill. Is there a way to monitor and potentially kill with the same app?

Comment: @Sparkler The Unix philosophy relies heavily on the idea of many applications that do one thing and do it really well. I personally don't know of an all-in-one application that would do that (that doesn't mean it doesn't exist). The way I would do it would be to `sudo iotop -P`. The leftmost column will show the process ID (PID). Once you know the PID of the process you want to kill, use `kill <PID>`. But I would use it with great caution.

Comment: What about the work carried out by that process? You don't care that you my lose something?

Comment: @Kusalananda sometimes you don't have a choice. Sometimes it's so intense the system is barely responding.