# Monitor disk io for most writers

Tags: monitoring, disk

I need to find out which process if likely responsible for damaging SD card on raspberri pi due to excessive io. So far `sudo iotop -aoP` almost cut it. Got it from the answer on
[How can I monitor disk io?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55212/how-can-i-monitor-disk-io/122807#122807)

```
Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :       0.00 B/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s
  PID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
 3200 be/4 pi            0.00 B      8.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % apache2 -k start
 2001 be/4 pi            0.00 B      8.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % apache2 -k start
  852 be/4 pi            0.00 B      8.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % apache2 -k start
 3194 be/4 pi            0.00 B      8.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % apache2 -k start
  856 be/4 pi            0.00 B      8.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % apache2 -k start
  855 be/4 pi            0.00 B      8.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % apache2 -k start
14757 be/4 root          0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/u8:1]
  959 be/4 pi            0.00 B     16.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % apache6.45 Ktart
```

`apache6.45 Ktart` looks like a terminal refresh bug. `iotop` data is not enough:

1. `iotop` shows writers that were active in the last (few?) second and I need a list of top writer since the tool was started.
2. It doesn't sort writers by most K written.
3. I need an average write speed of each writer over the last minute. It shows only average speed for last (few?) second.
4. There is no summary of avg/writing speed over last minute (or since program start).

So is there a way/tool to get such accumulated disk io stats per process?

Comment: `sysstat` provides `sar` command, which you can use for multiple things, including disk

Comment: @ILMostro_7 can it do disk things that I needed?

Comment: `atop` might be another tool to check out.  It creates a snapshot view, based on the configured time intervals, of the processes and other useful info.  You might find it more suitable for your specific needs.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the man page of iotop, which has several options.

```
iotop shows writers that were active in the last (few?) second and
I need a list of top writer since the tool was started.
```

Use the `-a` option to ask `iotop` to accumulate the data.

```
It doesn't sort writers by most K written.
```

Use the arrow keys to change the column of sorting. By default the IO percentage column is sorted.

```
I need an average write speed of each writer over the last minute.
It shows only average speed for last (few?) second.
```

Use the `-d` option to specify the update interval.

Comment: You should point put the man pages too, `man iotop`