# Is there a tool like vnstat but for hard disks to monitor their daily/monthly/yearly activity?

Tags: debian, hard-disk, ssd

There's a tool called `vnstat` which can monitor how much data you send/receive via network interfaces over time. Is there a similar tool for hdd/ssd disks? Basically I just want to know how much data I write to my disks daily/monthly/yearly.

Comment: Would [dstat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dstat) [iotop](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iotop) and/or [iostat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat) be the kind of tools you are looking for?

Comment: There are a lot of them. `sar`/`sysstat` is a traditional one, but there are *many* newer, prettier, more user-friendly tools. A related question (which mentions only a tiny portion of the available tools) is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55212/how-can-i-monitor-disk-io ... It's really hard to answer your question just because there are so many options available, in complexity ranging from things like dstat all the way up to feeding hundreds of machines worth of data into a time-series DB. It's not as daunting as "is there a program to edit text files?", but...

Comment: What's hard? I just want to know the total GiB my disk write/read each day/month/year, similar to the SSD feature. `iostat` looks promising, but I have to test that.

Comment: @kemotep  The `iostats` are reset after system reboot, so none of the three.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the default filesystem type - and you don't mind scripting something yourself to log the cumulative values :) - there's a feature of ext4 that's  convenient for this:

`sudo tune2fs -l $DEVICE` shows a "Lifetime writes" field.  Or you can use `cat /sys/fs/ext4/$DEVICE/lifetime_write_kbytes`

Comment: It's a good solution for an ext4 file system, but I need the value for the whole disk -- it also has the SWAP partition.